# CRC failure quote

Tags: crc, crc16

I am recently using CRC 8 to check my data for bit errors. My data is 320 bytes long. How high is the probability for not detecting bit errors when using 8-bit CRC with 320 bytes of data?

I honestly couldn't find any information on the failure quote. So far it worked fine, but I'm just curious of how good it will work and if there is a need to go to 16-bit CRC. The polynomial I'm using is 0x07.

Thanks!

Comment: What googling "crc probability of undetected error" is yielding? For me it's 35k results.

Comment: This is not a programming but a general mathematical question. There are documents detailing CRCs which you should read. Briefly: there is no simple answer.

Comment: @Olaf: That's okay. The site tour specifically states that questions about "software algorithms" are on topic. CRCs are widely used in programming, and their algorithm has some properties (error detection rate) that I think can be reasonably discussed in a programming forum like Stack Overflow. @ Darius: [This page may interest you](http://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/CRC-Math-Theory). CRCs may detect some errors with a 100% rate (e.g. single bit flips), but in general an 8-bit checksum can only catch up to ~99.6% of all possible errors due to collisions.

Comment: @Cornstalks: It is not. You want to read [ask]. And CRCs are not "software algorithms". Actually they were (and are) implemented in hardware. And we are **not** a discussion site.

Comment: @Olaf: Not all CRCs are implemented in hardware. The ones I've worked with were all implemented in software. And I think you may have read a little too much into my use of "discussion." Asking a question and getting an answer is a form of discussion. I wasn't referring to long back-and-forth conversations that take place on other forums. A better word probably exists, but alas, "discussion" is the first word that came to mind, and I haven't been able to think of a better one.

Comment: I did not say they are **all** implemented in hardware! Chances are quite good I have work with CRCs both, in software **and** hardware than you have. Anyway, that is not the point and also not what SO is for. As little as discussion-related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the message doesn't matter, so long as it's at least eight bits. Then the probability of a false positive with a large number of errors is 1/256. For a small number of errors the probability of a false positive can be zero. A burst of eight bit errors in a row will always be detected with no false positives.

In general an *n*-bit CRC will have a false positive rate of 2<sup>-n</sup> for more than *n* errors in the message, which can be any length.

Comment: I don't really get - why is the probability of undetected errors not depending on the data length? Shouldn't I have more undetected errors on a bigger file?

Comment: The probability of errors slipping by of course depends on the message (actually: polygon) length. It also depends on the type of errors (single bits, sequence, sequence length, etc.). Additionally some polygons provide better detection than other for the same length.

Comment: The probability of _having_ errors in the first place is likely to be a function of the message length, depending on the details of the error source. However the probability that more errors than the CRC length will not be _detected_ by the CRC is simply the probability that the CRC of the corrupted message accidentally turns out to be the CRC of the original message. It is easy to see that that probability is one over the number of possible CRC values.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Stupid me:-) No idea why I wrote polygon.

Comment: @MarkAdler: And the probability of a collising of course rises with the length of the message. Otherwise there would be no reason to use longer poly_nomials_ for longer messages. Said that, you still ignore the fact that for same length there are better and worse polynomials.

Comment: _A._ The probability of a collision is independent of the message length, so long as the CRC-_n_ can be any of the _2^n_ possible values. Which all proper CRC-_n_'s can for messages that are _n_ bits or longer.

Comment: _B._ Polynomials are better or worse only for small numbers of errors. See Koopman's papers where he looked at Hamming Weights up to 19 in order to find the "best" CRC-32 polynomial. For a large number of errors, as compared to the CRC length (not the message length) the polynomials are all the same, as well as any other decent non-CRC hash of the same length, so long as they satisfy some basic properties that provide complete coverage of all of the possible _n_-bit values.